# Where should be C# based Code placed in the MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I am currently working on the MVC 5 based project. Now for retrieving the few text content from Database, I have made the API call to get the text to be used in the View. Here my View is a basically simple form where few of the text comes from Database.

Now while loading the Page, I found that Image is not loaded initially while the page is being loaded. I am bringing the Image path from the Database using API call where I have stored the particular list of data from Cache.

Now I am not sure about where should I put a call to API. I am created the common function to make the call to API to retrieve the Data.

I have to option to choose from

1) Place the Call directly inside the Src attribute inside my image tag

```
<img src="@myfunctioncall" style="max-height:50px;" />
```

2) On the top of the View, Inside the C# block, I should declare the variable and then make a call to API and then use that variable inside the Src attribute inside my image tag.

On top of the View

```
@{
string myVal = myfunctioncall;
}
```

then use myVal  inside my img tag

```
.........Code......
<img src="@myVal" style="max-height:50px;" />
.........Code......
```

I am not sure about how the page is rendered and which is the best approach to get the job done.

Comment: It should not be in your view at at. The call to the method should be in the controller (where you can test it) and you pass a model to the view containing the result of that call.

Comment: View is not designed to deal with code logic, the logic tasks should be handled by controller action method instead. You can utilize viewmodel to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right approach is:

1) Build a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public string ImagePath {get;set;}
     //other properties
}
```

2) Controller:

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       MyModel model = new MyModel();
       model.ImagePath = //here get it from service
       return View(model);
    }
}
```

3) View:

```
<img src="@Model.ImagePath" style="max-height:50px;" />
```

In the first line of the View you need to add:

```
@model MyModel
```

---

Another (not suggested) option is:

`ViewBag` that is not strongly typed, as it's type is `dynamic`, which means errors in typos etc won't get caught in the build process, but in the runtime.

Controller:

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       ViewBag.ImagePath = //your service call
       return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<img src="@ViewBag.ImagePath" style="max-height:50px;" />
```

---

The idea to put a service call in the `View` is the violation of `MVC` pattern, where `View` supposed to be as stupid as possible. 
It's just representation layer.

Comment: I know this approach very well. The issue with my view is that it's being shared at many places and I cant add the new property to the module I am currently passing to view because already Model is loaded with my Properties though I know no restriction for the same. Another approach you mention ViewData but I personally don't prefer it.

Comment: What if you Create a ViewModel, that will add what you need and keep Model as property. It could be generic. Example: public T Model {get;set;} and public string ImagePath {get;set;} and use that?

Answer (score 2):

In the controller, you have to write the code to retrieve data from the database and then create a view Bag as `ViewBag.Path= imagePath;` where `imagePath` is the c# string variable in which it contains the path value retrieved from the database.Then in the View you can use the ViewBag as `<img src="@ViewBag.Path" style="max-height:50px;" />`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make all operation in your controller et make an object you pass as Model to your view.

In your view, your can use your Model for fill your field.